# Zend Framework 2 dependency injection - array of objects

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

ZF2 is not well documented. I want to inject to my object array of objects using array configuration:

```
public function __construct(array $transliterators)
```

When I write:

```
'Ddd\Slug\Infra\Transliterator\TransliteratorCollection' => array(
    'parameters' => [
        'transliterators' => [
            'Ddd\Slug\Infra\Transliterator\LatinTransliterator'
        ]
    ]
),
```

strings are pased instead of objects. These objects are also defined in di. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Why do you use Zend\Di and not the default & recommended Zend\ServiceManager? It's by far easier to get the SM working than DI and actually Zend\Di is quite unmaintained.

Comment: Can you propose solution for my case in `SM` instead of `Di` without using factory and callback function in separate anwer (this will give me opportunity to mark your answer are correct and upvote)? BTW I am caching config file, so callback function doesn't work, because calss names are randomized.

Comment: For what reason do you want to avoid factories then? If you need to inject dependencies and closures are no option (which is a good options BTW) for Zend\ServiceManager you're only left with factories. They're perfectly fine to work with; Zend\ServiceManager just doesn't do auto-wiring based on configuration, it's more explicit than Zend\Di